# C# enums are similar to Java enums

Tags: c#, java, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enum in Java. Advantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages)

But Java enums are classes. And c# enums (to my knowledge) aren't. What are the benefits of Java's implementation of enums?

Comment: They may be used in Java, unlike C# enums ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-sharp-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c

Comment: There's much that can be learned about this subject here: https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+enums+vs+java+enums

Comment: Your "to my knowledge" is correct; they are simply named integers, with some additional compiler handling,

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages