# Which access modifier should I use for constants?

Tags: java, coding-style

```
public static final
```

or

```
private static final
```

Considering cases when constants are used only from class itself. Which style is preferable?

Comment: `private` If it's not needed outside of the class, then why expose it?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need these values in the class, they should be `private`. In general make things as inaccessible as possible and only increase accessibility when necessary.

Comment: True - but often in practice it's useful to make constants also accessible to unit tests for the class, so you'd end up making the constant have package-only visibility (neither private nor public)

Answer (score 1):

`private` should be used when using multiple classes. You can use a getter if you need to access its value.

`public` should only really be used when you have just one class.

Comment: The question is about constants, and you can't have a setter for a constant (nor would you need a getter). Not sure what you mean by using multiple classes or having just one class.

Answer (score 1):

If the constant only needs to be accessed in the class it is in, using

```
private static void
```

or even just

```
static final
```

would work, since it is not needed to be called elsewhere.

However, if private static final is used for the constant, it is good practice to use a getter to call the constant, like this:

```
private static final String CONSTANTVARIABLE = "Some constant";

public String getConstantVariable() {
  return CONSTANTVARIABLE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not be lazy, and just do

```
    static final
```

I think it's better to start with 'package' access; you might needed it in unit test at least. Then you may change it to public/private or protected if you must.

'private' is usually not necessary - you seldom need to worry that other classes under the same package may screw up this class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **`enum`** for the same. They are actually designed to serve the purpose of `constant` along with flexibility to add functionality later if needed.

> Just have a look at the following links to [compare constants with enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages) and many more links you ll get. I just posted some of them.