# Reusing static initialization block

Tags: java, enums, static-initialization

I've found using a static initialization block in an Enum to be great for implementing a custom valueOf function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572450/779).

```
public static RandomEnum getEnum(String strVal) {
    return strValMap.get(strVal);
}

private static final Map<String, RandomEnum> strValMap;
static {
    final Map<String, RandomEnum> tmpMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    for(final RandomEnum en : RandomEnum.values()) {
        tmpMap.put(en.strVal, en);
    }
    strValMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(tmpMap);
}
```

Now, I have about two dozen of Enum classes and I want to add a custom valueOf for all of them -- is there a way to do that without copy-pasting it into every single type/file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a private static function, and use it multiple times in the initialization block. You could also assign the result of that function to your maps, without the static block at all:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>> Map<String,E> makeValueMap(E[] values) {
    final Map<String,E> tmpMap = new HashMap<String,E>();
    for(final E en : values) {
        tmpMap.put(en.name(), en);
    }
    return tmpMap;
}
```

Now you can write

```
private static final Map<String,RandomEnum> strValMap1 = makeValueMap(RandomEnum.values());
private static final Map<String,AnotherEnum> strValMap2 = makeValueMap(AnotherEnum.values());
private static final Map<String,YetAnotherEnum> strValMap3 = makeValueMap(YetAnotherEnum.values());
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/vahjwJ)

Answer (score 0):

To implement the same mechanism **WITHIN** the enum classes, I guess no, because an enum cannot inherit from a class (only interfaces), hence has no way to share implementations.

You can, however, implement a standalone utility that does this for all the different enum types together. The utility will look up enum values by enum type + strVal.