# What happens when we pass an argument to System.out.println()?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I am not able to understand how println() function actually works. When I pass primitive variable to it . It prints value of it. When I pass an object why does it print default toString() method definition? i.e.

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

So when I am trying to print out an array.

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))
```

Am I overriding default method definition of toString of Object class or just converting Array to String using toString() method of Arrays class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class RevString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "abcde";
        int x=2;
        String[] e =str.split("---");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)+ " " +"Primitive is " + " " + x);

    }

}
```

Comment: It does use `toString()` method.  Unless it's overridden somewhere in the inheritance chain, the one from `Object` will be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support println in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647567/how-to-support-println-in-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toString()` method if not overridden, will inherit from the object class.
so you need to override it it in your class to be capable of showing the members o your object.

Current IDEs have this option automatic, so you just right click and generate toString method with the class members

look at [this](http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/).

Answer (score 2):

> When I pass an object why does it print default toString() method definition?

Because it's defined in the [Java specification Chapter 5 § 1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression ([§15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)):
>
> - If T is boolean, then use new Boolean(x).
> - If T is char, then use new Character(x).
> - If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x).
> - If T is long, then use new Long(x).
> - If T is float, then use new Float(x).
> - If T is double, then use new Double(x).
>
> This reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

`.toString` takes the variable's value and changes it to a String. I do not believe it actually changes the libraries definition. This may help: [Override valueof() and toString() in Java enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662170/java-override-valueof-and-tostring-in-enum)

Comment: I like GingerHead's answer better, but if my one helped, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a println() method for every primitive and one for Objects. Primitives are printed as String.valueOf('primitive') whereas Objects are printed as 'object'.toString()