# Customizing enum constant names with Jackson

Tags: java, enums, jackson, fasterxml

I have an enum defined as

```
public enum Locale {
  EN_US, ES_MX
}
```

These locale, however, are written as lowercase strings with hyphen as `en-us` and `es-mx` in data.

Is there a way to map these lowercase strings to corresponding enum constants? Like `en-us` to `EN_US`?

**EDIT**
Let me provide more information. I have an object of the following class.

```
public class Song {
  private Map<Locale, String> songName;
  private int durationMillis;
}
```

A song's name can vary by Locale. So I create a map for the song's name in various Locales.

I have a JSON file with info on songs. It reads like:

```
{
  "songs": [
    {
      "songName": {"en-us":"Song name in US english", "es-mx": "Song name in Spanish"},
      "durationMillis": 100000
    },
    {
      "songName": {"en-us": "another song name -  English"},
      "durationMillis": 200000
    }
  ]
}
```

I define another class.

```
public class Songs {
  private Set<Song> songs;
}
```

I use FasterXml's `ObjectMapper` to load the JSON as an object of `Songs` class.

```
Songs songs = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Songs.class);
```

This above line crashed right now because `ObjectMapper` cannot map `en-us` string to `Locale.EN_US`.

I can always edit the enum and define it as

```
public enum Locale {
  EN_US("en-us"),
  ES_MX("es-mx");

  private String value;
  Locale(String val){
    value = val;
  }
}
```

But I have seen a smarter way somewhere, which converted the lowercase hyphenated string to uppercase underscored literal. Can you point me to that solution?

I need a solution such that FasterXml's `ObjectMapper` can map the string to enum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override valueof() and toString() in Java enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662170/override-valueof-and-tostring-in-java-enum)

Comment: @jhamon: it's not a duplicate. I don't have flexibility in calling a specific method of the defined enum. I don't know what method Jackson's ObjectMapper would call. It probably works only with the constructor.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since [Jackson 2.6](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/commit/c2fe43a911d2143d77c20fa08bd5b6e662427cd0), you can annotate your enum constants with `@JsonProperty` to give them a custom name. The [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) states

> Starting with Jackson 2.6 this annotation may also be used to change
>   serialization of `Enum` like so:
>
> ```
> public enum MyEnum {
>     @JsonProperty("theFirstValue") THE_FIRST_VALUE,
>     @JsonProperty("another_value") ANOTHER_VALUE;
> }
> ```

In your case, you'd use

```
public enum Locale {
  @JsonProperty("en-us") EN_US, @JsonProperty("es-mx") ES_MX
}
```

---

Alternatively, assuming all enum constants follow the same naming pattern, you can use [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html). Define an instance method annotated with `@JsonValue` in your enum type and implement it with your naming strategy. For example,

```
@JsonValue
public String forJackson() {
    return name().toLowerCase().replace('_', '-');
}
```

You get the nice benefit of

> when use for Java enums, one additional feature is that value returned
>   by annotated method is also considered to be the value to deserialize
>   from, not just JSON String to serialize as. This is possible since set
>   of Enum values is constant and it is possible to define mapping, but
>   can not be done in general for POJO types; as such, this is not used
>   for POJO deserialization.

It'll be used for both serialization and deserialization.

---

<sub>Avoid naming your types with names already appearing in the JDK. Java already provides a commonly used [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) type. Consider renaming your class.</sub>