# What is the advantage of using enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

I was going through the enums in Java. It seems that the same things that enums can do can be achieved by collections or an array of Strings or user-defined types.

What is the main purpose of introducing enums in Java 5?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419835/understanding-enums-in-java/1419849#1419849) for a good answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Advantages -

- Set of Constant declaration
- Restrict input parameter in method
- Can be usable in switch-case

It is used for *fields consist of a fixed set of constants*.

Example is `Thread.State`

```
public enum State {
    NEW,
    RUNNABLE,
    WAITING,
    BLOCKED,
    ...
}
```

or `private enum Alignment { LEFT, RIGHT };`

You can restrict input parameter using `Enum` like-

```
String drawCellValue (int maxCellLnghth, String cellVal, Alignment align){}
```

Here in align parameter could be only `Alignment.LEFT` or `Alignment.RIGHT` which is restricted.

Example of switch-case with `enum` -

```
String drawCellValue (int maxCellLnghth, String cellVal, Alignment align){
    switch (align) {
    case LEFT:...
    case RIGHT: ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 In Java, those "constants" are references to objects which can have immutable data or mutable state, and can be members of sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

one of it's uses was as a means to emulate a `switch` on Strings type variables as before Java 7 this was not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for the "type-safe enum pattern" (e.g. in the book "Effective Java" 1st edition, by Joshua Bloch). The Java "enum" construct is a language level support (syntactic sugar) for this design pattern.