# java Enum valueOf has two parameters?

Tags: java, enums

Why does `valueOf` have two parameters?

in [Java documentation for valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String))

> `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf​(Class<T> enumType, String name)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> enumType - the Class object of the enum type from which to return a constant
>
> name - the name of the constant to return

But most examples I read online says:

```
enum WorkDays {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY;
}
```

Test:

```
WorkDays day1 = WorkDays.valueOf("MONDAY");
System.out.println(day1); // >>>  MONDAY
```

It seems that the method used only one parameter?

Comment: Please read the documentation you referenced.

Comment: The entire second paragraph.

Comment: I actually find it confusing.....and still don't understand...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Enums in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419835/understanding-enums-in-java)

Comment: In a nutshell it says that you can do what you did. As I understand, The method you use is compiler-generated.

Comment: the two arguments method is declared in the `Enum` class, but there are also  implicitly declared methods `values` and `valueOf`: [8.9.3. Enum Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3). You could also have called  `Enum.valueOf(WorkDays.class, "MONDAY")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just examine the bytecode to see what happens when an `enum` is compiled:

```
public enum TestEnum {A, B}
```

And the bytecode of `valueOf`:

```
// access flags 0x9
public static valueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)LTestEnum;
 L0
  LINENUMBER 1 L0
  LDC LTestEnum;.class
  ALOAD 0
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Enum.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
  CHECKCAST TestEnum
  ARETURN
 L1
  LOCALVARIABLE name Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 0
  MAXSTACK = 2
  MAXLOCALS = 1
```

I am no expert in byte code but you can see that the line:

```
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Enum.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
```

In fact invokes `java.lang.Enum.valueOf`. A java equivalent would look like this:

```
public static TestEnum myValueOf(String name) {
    return Enum.valueOf(TestEnum.class, name);
}
```

And the bytecode confirms this:

```
// access flags 0x9
public static myValueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)LTestEnum;
 L0
  LINENUMBER 6 L0
  LDC LTestEnum;.class
  ALOAD 0
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Enum.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
  CHECKCAST TestEnum
  ARETURN
 L1
  LOCALVARIABLE name Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 0
  MAXSTACK = 2
  MAXLOCALS = 1
```

Comparing these two snippets you can see the difference is... yes, the name (and the line number):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Showing the byte code does add another layer of insight

Answer (score 7):

As you indicated in previous comments that you find the text in the documentation confusing, and since your profile indicates you are a novice programmer:

Enum is the superclass of all enums you will declare.
In your example, WorkDays can be seen as a specific case of the Enum class.
The valueOf() static method documentation is writen for this parent Enum class.
Meaning that in your case, it would be called as:
`Enum.valueOf(WorkDays.class, "MONDAY")`.

Now, since you made your own Enum (i.e. WorkDays), you don't need to use this static parent method. You can just use the method that is exposed by your self-created enum.

```
WorkDays.valueOf("Monday")
```

This is "implicitly declared" meaning that it will be there for every one of your self-created enums.

Answer (score 4):

The snippet you shared uses the implicitly declared method referenced in the second paragraph:

> Note that for a particular enum type `T`, the implicitly declared `public static T valueOf(String)` method on that enum may be used instead of this method to map from a name to the corresponding enum constant.

The first paragraph refers to calling the method via the `Enum` class:

```
System.out.println(Enum.valueOf(WorkDays.class, "MONDAY"));
```